# Change color of a line separator in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

Is there is any way to change the color of a line ("vertical line" and "horizontal line" of Interface Builder). A line separator in IB is a NSBox and I didn't find any method to change color when is used as NSBoxSeparator.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It doesn't look like the line color is exposed for the "line" convenience object, but it is for the regular NSBox.

You can use a regular NSBox with its Box Type set to Custom and its border color set to whatever you desire. Then just size it down to a single pixel width or height.

Comment: That simple?!? (It´s obvious that I´m newbie, isn´t it?)

Comment: Well, to be fair, if it can be controlled in the NSBox inspector, why not the line (which is still an NSBox). UI failing, not yours. :-) Remember to mark answers that work for you as accepted - this community works on karma points.

Comment: Plus, it helps future readers know that the answer worked for the questioner.

Comment: Yeah, that too, I suppose. ;-)